# Receiving un expected data over serial io c#

Tags: c#, .net, io, serial-port

I am trying to write a command format over serial port and expecting a reply. In the receiving process i am receiving some unknown data pattern along with whatever have written as command even when I am not writing the same pattern or data on the other end.

**Serial Port Creation**

```
port= new SerialPort(s, 9200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

**Send & Recieve**

```
   public byte[] SendAndRecieve(COMMAND request)
    {

        Console.Write("\nSendAndRecieve\n");    
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        byte retry = 0;
           bool flag = false;

           while (retry < 3)
           {
               /
               Console.Write("\n Send&Recive retry {0} \n",retry);
              WriteCommandAsByte(request.ToByteArray());

              Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                 while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000))
                  {

                      if (readBuffer == null)
                      {
                          flag = true;
                          break;
                      }

                  }
                if (flag)
                    break; 
                retry++;
           }

           return readBuffer;
    }
```

**Write Function**

```
public void WriteCommandAsByte(byte [] data)
    {

        try
        {


                Console.Write("\nWriting Data: ");
                foreach (byte bt in data)
                    Console.Out.Write(" {0:x2}", bt);
                Console.Write("\n\n");
                port.DiscardOutBuffer();
                port.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                port.Write("\n");
                port.DiscardOutBuffer();


        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WriteCommandAsByte Error");

        }


    }
```

**Serial Data Received event handler**

```
private  void Port_DataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Data Recieved\n");
                int ByteToRead = port.BytesToRead;
                readBuffer = new byte[ByteToRead];
                port.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                port.DiscardInBuffer();
                Console.WriteLine("\n Data:  \n\n");
                foreach (byte bt in readBuffer)
                    Console.Write(" {0:x2}", bt);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
             //Handle exceptions
        }
```

Request data :
**Writing Data:  01 01 01 00 00 01 00 31 40 c9**

Response:
 A Pattern **5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e**  & data what i sent  **31 40 c9** 
 
 **5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e 40 5e 41 5e** 40 31 40 c9 0d 0a 5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e 40 5e 41 5e 40 31 40 c9 0d 0a 5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e 40 5e 41
5e 40 31 40 c9 0d 0a 5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e 40 5e 41 5e 40 **31 40 c9** 0d 0a 5e 41 5e 41 5e 41 5e 40 5e 40 5e 41 5e 40 31 40 c9 

Why i am receiving whatever i write along with some unexpected data?

Comment: What kind of decvie is attached to the serial port?

Comment: USB Serial device

Comment: Which? I mean, you are asking what the received data means. The received data is obviously sent by something connected to the serial port. So in order to interpret it, you need to know what his device sends.

Comment: it is not something i am writing on the usb serial device c application.Some part of data what i am receiving is whatever i have written and some part of it some junk data and some from the device.

Comment: I noticed right away that your baud rate is fishy -- Did you mean 9600?   Different UARTS (like the one in your USB Serial device) may or may not try ot set it to what you ask.  Not sure what it will do if it's wrong.

Comment: Oh, and another couple of things ... your Write methodhas a DiscardOutputBuffer() call before AND AFTER you do your write. The one before is good, but the one after seems like it could cause you to not send some bytes, since the Write() call will buffer bytes and return before they are sent.  If you are stepping, or hitting breakpoints, you may not see this.

Answer (score 2):

You ignore the return value of the port.Read call which is the number of received bytes. Anything in readBuffer beyond this is not valid.

Comment: junk data is mainly comes at the beginning of the buffer. So cant simply skip after reading some bytes of data.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding your sample data at the end of the question. Could you please update your question and clearly write: what is sent from your c# program to the device, what do you think should be the response, what is the actual response?